# Создание визарда с предпросмотром

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужен пошаговый визард для редактирования модели. Остановился на [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/). Вопрос в следующем: есть требование заказчика на последнем шаге редактирования показать превью всех введенных данных чтобы типа клиент мог их посмотреть и вернуться если что-то захочет изменить. Подскажите как это сделать? Там нет такого примера... Как я понял данные на сервер отправляются в конце после всех шагов, а не после каждого? Значит наверное можно их как-то собрать все в кучу и сгенерировать превьюшку. Только не знаю как...

Comment: Собрать все данные и на последнем шаге вывести как превьюшку всё верно, примеры примерами а там есть Документация где всё описано как и зачем плагин работает, вот там и копайте. например метод getStep, который возвращает объект шага по индексу.

Comment: сделать одну форму, в форме много секций (1 секция - 1 шаг). Показывать секции по очереди, и в конце показать все.

Comment: @RifmaMan но этот метод возвращает html шага, а не значения полей

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц дословно пересказал то что написано выше. Зачем? О_о

Comment: Хмм, по идее можно воспользоваться методом [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) для получения значений полей, вот только как их потом вывести? Разве что вручную на последнем шаге добавить их на форму.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК, да, действительно в ответ getStep выдает html, если нужны данные с формы, вы совершенно правы, вы можете вытащить их из неё используя `serializeArray()`, вы также можете скопировать объекты через `jQuery.clone`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        section {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#" matod="POST">
            <section id="first">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Имя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="Name" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Surname">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Surname" id="Surname" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="nextBtn btn btn-success" value="Далее">
            </section>
            <section id="second">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Age">Возраст</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Age" id="Age" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Tel">Телефон</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Tel" id="Tel" aria-describedby="helpId"
                        autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="nextBtn btn btn-success" value="Далее">
            </section>
            <section id="all">
                <div id="content"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </section>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // массив с id секциями
        let mass = ['first', 'second', 'all'];
        // сюда заносятся информация с секцийй
        let info = [];
        // текущая секция
        let currentPage = 0;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // показываю текущую секцию
            $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).css("display", "block");

            // при клике на "Далее"
            $(".nextBtn").click(function () {
                // прячу текцщую секцию
                $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).css("display", "none");
                // проверяю, последняя секция или нет
                if (currentPage !== mass.length - 1) {
                    // временный массив с инфой по секции
                    let tempSectionValue = [];
                    // заношу имя инпата и значения во временны массив 
                    $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).find("input:not([type=button])").each(function () {
                        tempSectionValue.push({ "name": $(this).attr("name"), "value": $(this).val() });
                    });
                    // если сеции были уже заполнены
                    if (info.length === mass.length - 1) {
                        // ищу по id и изменяю
                        info.forEach(section => {
                            if (section.sectionId === currentPage){
                                section.sectionValue = tempSectionValue;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    // если нет то просто добавляю
                    else {
                        info.push({ "sectionId": currentPage, "sectionValue": tempSectionValue });
                    }

                }
                // следующая страница
                currentPage++;
                // если секция последняя
                if (currentPage === mass.length - 1) {
                    // временная строка, котороую потом вставлять буду
                    let strAppend = "";
                    // чисщу прошлый контент
                    $("#content").empty();
                    // добавляю информацию согласно массива
                    info.forEach(function (section) {
                        strAppend = "";
                        section.sectionValue.forEach(function (input) {
                            strAppend +=
                                '<div class="row">' +
                                '<label>' + input.name + '</lable>' +
                                '<div>' + input.value + '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                                ;
                        });
                        $("#content").append(
                            strAppend +
                            '<input onclick="edit(' + section.sectionId + ')" class="btn btn-info" value="Изменить">'
                        );
                    });
                }
                // отображаю уже новую секцию
                $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).css("display", "block");
            });
        });

        // для редактирования
        function edit(id) {
            $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).css("display", "none");
            currentPage = id;
            $("section#" + mass[currentPage]).css("display", "block");
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```